# Is it safe to upgrade from Magento 2.4.5-p1 to the latest version and how to best do that?

Tags: upgrade

```
Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
```

I've had terrible problems with Magento 2.4.2-p1 so I really try to avoid doing things that could potentially cause me such problems on this new site I'm developing.

When I log into my Magento 2.4.5-p1, there is a pop-up that says something about upgrading to MAGENTO 2.6.0.

**Is this a good idea and if so, what is the best way for me to upgrade?**